# How to ensure all the async calls are back in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of javascript code doing

```
function asyncs(){
    var backCount = 0;
    function done(){
        if(backCount === 2){
            alert("All done");
            doSomthingUseful();
        }else{
            backCount ++;
        }
    }
    function asyncCall(callBack){
        myRemoteCall(callBack);
    }
    asyncCall(done);
    asyncCall(done);
    asyncCall(done);
}

function doSomethingUseful(){
    alert("Travel to the moon.")
}
```

This is working. But I am wondering if there is a better approach so that I don't have to write this ugly counter function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a flow control library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [Nimble](http://caolan.github.com/nimble/) to handle this sort of thing. Internally   it does pretty much the same thing but it gives you them in reusable patterns.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to do what I want, but I think it's a bit over kill. I will keep looking.

Comment: @WeiMa If you're looking for a lighter solution, I would recommend [Nimble](http://caolan.github.com/nimble/) which has similar functionality but is much smaller.

Comment: Thanks. I will use one of the libraries.